# How do you post images on the i.stack.imgur page?

Tags: support

When looking through some of the riddles on the puzzler SE, I noticed that quite a few of them used images that they posted on the i.stack.imgur page. When I went on that page, all I got was this:
[image]
Is there something that I need to do to post images on this page, or is the website down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only upload images when you're creating or editing a post. So, if you're writing a question there should be a toolbar with this icon: [image]. Clicking that icon or using <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> will open up the image uploader. From there you can click to browse your files, upload from a link, drag and drop, or paste to upload your image.

...Of course, it looks like you know this already, otherwise how did you get that image uploaded?!

Answer (score 0):

That's kind of due to a special arrangement that SO/SE has with imgur. It's meant for posting images on Stack Exchange and use of the image uploader on any SE site's posting or chat functionality will use imgur. There's no other way to use the 'stack' branded imgur instance